# References on functions FindGraphPartition and FindGraphCommunties

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details

Does somebody have some interesting references on the `FindGraphPartition` and `FindGraphCommunties[.., Method -> "Spectral"]` functions and their algorithms as implemented by *Mathematica* 9.

Comment: The _Applications_ of the documentation has interesting references. [FindGraphPartition](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGraphPartition.html) and [FindGraphCommunities](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGraphCommunities.html).

Comment: I mean scientifically notably with spectral method

Comment: Have you made a Google search? What did you find? Why wasn't it sufficient?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question or worthy of downvotes. Of course one can't find information on implementation details simply by searching on the general terms mentioned in the documentation. At best, you can find information about implementations in general, with no way of knowing which one is used in *Mathematica*. Other functions have references to specific literature, and I don't think it's unreasonable to ask for references for these functions as well. (Sometimes these can be found in the `Combinatorica\`` source code.)

Comment: @Oleksandr R Yes I see documentation but is not enough for me.These functions are not in combinatorica package so I can't see source code

Comment: The [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) package implements many community detection algorithms. The documentation has references to the original publications for each method.

Answer (score 5):

What the exact implementation is in Mathematica, I don't know. You can't know unless you have access to the source code or part of the research team. Assuming, however, that they used the fairly standard technique of spectral modularity maximization I hope these references are useful:

- [Modularity and community structure in networks](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/23/8577.abstract), Proceedings of the National Academy of Science of the United States, vol. 103 no. 23. The preprint is [also available](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0602124). A nice introduction to spectral modularity maximization can be found in [Networks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199206651) by M.Newman, chapter 11.
- [Community detection modularity suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdmsuite/) is an open source project which contains C++ and R implementations of the concepts explained in the articles.
- [An Effcient Spectral Algorithm for Network Community Discovery
  and Its Applications to Biological and Social Networks](http://cs.utsa.edu/~jruan/papers/icdm07_short.pdf) elaborates on a more efficient approach.

Comment: many thanks for references

Comment: You shouldn't thank, but rather upvote or mark as an answer.