# Where can I find documentation on the methods/algorithm used in FindGraphPartition in Mathematica 10?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, implementation-details, documentation, cluster-analysis

I am working on a graph theoretical project where it would be helpful to know the name of the algorithm used in `FindGraphPartition`.

**Question:**

Where can I find details on what methods are used in this specific function? If there are no official details or documentation available, does anyone know how *Mathematica* might solve this problem? Is there any direction you can point me in to begin my research?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46824/12), but I won't vote to close.  If you were asking the same about `FindGraphCommunities` (which is a bit different), I would direct you to [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM), which also has many community finding algorithms implemented, and the documentation has references for each algorithm.

Comment: The question to which you link is a question about Mathematica 9. I am using Mathematica 10. Is there significant enough difference between the two to warrant a separate question, and if so, do you recommend I change the question phrasing to reflect that?

Comment: I doubt that anyone can answer this question here.  What you must do is contact [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/) and ask.  If they respond, please let us know what they said.  Do not delete this question.  They are usually, but not always, good in giving references.  I asked about this in June 2015.  I got a response saying that they passed on the question to the developers.  Then I never heard back.  In October I asked again, but received no response that time.

Comment: It really isn't that relevant that you have M10 instead of M9.  The point is: please ask support, then if they respond, come back and post an answer yourself.

Comment: Ok. Just emailed the technical support team about it. Will post here if they respond with anything useful.

Comment: Did they respond to you?  Did they say anything useful?

Comment: Yes and no. They reposed say thing that their methods are confidential

Comment: So they give us a function but they won't tell us what it does.  Wonderful.  What's the point of the function then?

Comment: Just to note: this is not only about *how* it does what it does.  It's also about making it clear what the function computes, which simply isn't described in the documentation.  "finds a partition of vertices such that the number of edges having endpoints in different parts is minimized." is not clear because it doesn't agree at all with FindEdgeCut.  There is obviously some constraint about the size of partitions too.